# How to animate level adjustments in Photoshop CS6 timeline

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I've created a hue/saturation level adjustment in Photoshop CS6.

[image]

Now I have a timeline with 2 frames. I want the second frame to have a different "Hue" value:

[image]

As I change the slider, the change is propagated to all the frames in the timeline. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

Animate the opacity level of the hue layer to fade in the second layer 0% to 100%.
You can then duplicate the second layer and change the hue settings and fade that one in too and so on i have just made an animation with 8 layers of hue 0,+50,+100,+150 etc.[image]

PS this is animated as a timeline it can easily be turned into frame animation if thats the type you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a sort of psychedelic effect, the hue keeps changing for the pattern. If so, I have a solution that would work for your use case.

1. **Create the layer** you want to change the hue of (*state 1*).
2. **Duplicate and change the hue** to the final hue you want (*state 2*).
3. Now you have two layers, **switch the second layer visibility off
   for the first animation frame (*state 1*), and switch it on for the
   last animation frame (*state 2*), and then tween** the animation
   frames between these.
4. If you want it to be a continuous loop, **duplicate the first frame,
   move it to the end, and tween the frames** between *state 2* and
   *state 1* again (ideally adding the same number of frames as you did last time for symmetry)

Comment: unfortunately, tweening won't create the same effect as moving the slider. If I tween from hue -180 to +180 the effect is completely different. I need to manually create each frame (from -180 to +180) which is insane. Thanks for your advice though! +1

Comment: double checked why it doesn't work the same way: tweening on 2 layers visibility will just animate their opacity, not the hue.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry I just thought this might work. Sorry it wasn't what you're looking for. Do let us know if you find a solution though. :)

Comment: yep, I've created a script that automatically creates 360 layers and a timeline switching their visibility... Would like to publish it, but it really sucks and serve just that purpose.